# JMS: Deliver String or Object as payload, which is relatively faster?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a simple `Person` object that contains some basic information about a person. If I want to send it by JMS:

1. I can convert this object into JSON, then deliver it as a `String` object.
2. I can use `Person` object as the payload directly.

I'm using ActiveMQ as JSM provider. Which way is faster?
And what if I need to send a `Map` or `List` as the payload?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the performance of serialization, not much about jms/activemq. So an ObjectMessage is a binary blob at transport that uses java serialization and for the string message, you can choose whatever serialization processor you want.

[This article with runnable benchmarks](https://github.com/RichardHightower/json-parsers-benchmark/wiki/Serialization-Jackson-vs.-Boon-vs.-Java-Serialization) shows that json serialization can be as fast as java object serialization. Although the article is obviously biased, you can note that also jackson/JSON serialization and java serialization is pretty close in terms of performance.

I guess you can measure yourself, with your kind of data. Either way, it's likely a micro optimization. If serialization speed truly matters that much, see if you can optimize in terms of size/quantity in terms objects sent.

As a final note, if you deal with very large payloads, the size and therefore the transport time will contribute to performance. In that case, you may want to make sure your json is not indented and possibly also compressed.

Comment: In ActiveMQ, will String payload be transformed by serialization, just like object payload?

Comment: hmm? I don't get it. A string is a string, not much to say about that.

Comment: String is also an object, so ActiveMQ might use serialization in String just like the object payload